# Boost asio multi threaded application serializes the timer callback

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, io, boost-asio

I have below application running on linux with boost library version 1.79.
The code is based on boost example taken from [here](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-scalability)

```
void worker(io_context& ioContext) {
    std::cerr << "Worker thread started." << std::endl;
    ioContext.run(); // Run the io_context to handle asynchronous operations
    std::cerr << "Worker thread stopped." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    try {
        io_context ioContext;

        // Create a work object to prevent ioContext.run() from returning immediately
        io_context::work work(ioContext);

        // Create multiple worker threads
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            threads.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(ioContext));
        }


        boost::asio::steady_timer timer(ioContext, std::chrono::seconds(5));

        // Set a lambda function as the callback when the timer expires
        timer.async_wait(
            [](const boost::system::error_code& error) {
                if (error)
                {
                    std::cerr << "async_wait failed: "
                                        << error.message();
                    return;
                }
                std::cerr << "Sleep Start Task1 executed in thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
                sleep(60);
            });

        boost::asio::steady_timer timer1(ioContext, std::chrono::seconds(10));

        // Set a lambda function as the callback when the timer expires
        timer1.async_wait(
            [](const boost::system::error_code& error) {
                if (error)
                {
                    std::cerr << "async_wait failed: "
                                        << error.message();
                    return;
                }
                std::cerr << " Start Task2 executed in thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
            });


        std::cerr << "App started :" << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
        // Join the worker threads
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        std::cerr << "All worker threads joined." << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that the two threads can execute the timer callbacks concurrently.

My expectation was

Thread 1 - Will call timer 1 callback after 5 sec and sleep for 60 sec (blocking call)

Thread 2 - Will call timer2 callback after 10 sec

when I run the code, the results seem to indicate that all timer callbacks are serialized on a single thread.

after 5 seconds
Sleep Start Task executed in thread: 1991504768

after 60 seconds
Start Task executed in thread: 1991504768

I am not able to understand why the timer callbacks are serialized when there are two threads running ioContext.run();

anything I am doing wrong ? any other feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `sleep(60)` in your handler. That's going to block a service thread, interfering with scheduling.

Regardless of that, I cannot reproduce the problem. Adding some measurements along the way (and reducing the time intervals to fit my patience levels better):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1168907041deb6d)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

static std::atomic_int tid_gen = 0;
thread_local int const tid     = [] { return ++tid_gen; }();
static constexpr auto  now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto const      start   = now();
static std::mutex console_mx;

void trace(auto const&... msg) {
    std::lock_guard lk(console_mx);
    std::cerr << "at " << std::setw(8) << (now() - start)/1ms << "ms - tid:" << tid << " ";
    (std::cerr << ... << msg) << std::endl;
}

void worker(asio::io_context& ioContext) {
    trace("Worker thread enter");
    ioContext.run(); // Run the io_context to handle asynchronous operations
    trace("Worker thread exit");
}

int main() {
    try {
        asio::io_context ioContext;

        // Create a work object to prevent ioContext.run() from returning immediately
        auto work = make_work_guard(ioContext);

        // Create multiple worker threads
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            threads.emplace_back(worker, std::ref(ioContext));
        }

        asio::steady_timer task1(ioContext, 50ms);
        asio::steady_timer task2(ioContext, 100ms);

        task1.async_wait([](error_code ec) {
            trace("Start Task1: ", ec.message());
            if (!ec)
                sleep(6);
        });

        task2.async_wait([](error_code ec) { trace("Start Task2: ", ec.message()); });

        trace("App started :", std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

        work.reset();
        // Join the worker threads
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        trace("All worker threads joined.");
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        trace("Exception: ", std::quoted(e.what()));
    }
}
```

Printing

```
at        0ms - tid:1 Worker thread enter
at        0ms - tid:2 Worker thread enter
at        0ms - tid:3 App started :4
at       50ms - tid:1 Start Task1: Success
at      100ms - tid:2 Start Task2: Success
at     6050ms - tid:1 Worker thread exit
at     6050ms - tid:2 Worker thread exit
at     6050ms - tid:3 All worker threads joined.
```

Which is exactly what I'd expect

Side note: use `thread_pool` and actually get a pool automatically sized based on hardware concurrency, do away with the work guard and other simplifications:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aee6e9c4fff0eb63)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using boost::system::error_code;

static std::atomic_int tid_gen = 0;
thread_local int const tid     = [] { return ++tid_gen; }();

using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
static constexpr auto now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto const     start = now();
static std::mutex     console_mx;

void trace(auto const&... msg) {
    std::lock_guard lk(console_mx);
    std::cerr << "at " << std::setw(8) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms - tid:" << tid << " ";
    (std::cerr << ... << msg) << std::endl;
}

void do_task(error_code ec, std::string caption, duration block_for = {}) {
    trace("Start ", caption, ": ", ec.message());
    if (!ec)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(block_for);
}

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool io;

    asio::steady_timer task1(io, 50ms);
    asio::steady_timer task2(io, 100ms);

    task1.async_wait(bind(do_task, _1, "Task1", 6s));
    task2.async_wait(bind(do_task, _1, "Task2", 0s));

    trace("App started: ", std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

    io.join();
    trace("Done");
}
```

Prints

```
at        0ms - tid:1 App started: 4
at       50ms - tid:2 Start Task1: Success
at      100ms - tid:3 Start Task2: Success
at     6051ms - tid:1 Done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code and I am getting different result. Same as my original problem.                                                                                                                                  at        1ms - tid:1 App started :2
at       30ms - tid:2 Worker thread enter
at       30ms - tid:3 Worker thread enter
at       50ms - tid:2 Start Task1: Success
at     6050ms - tid:2 Start Task2: Success
at     6051ms - tid:2 Worker thread exit

Comment: My hardware is Dual-core ARM Cortex A7, running Linux 5.15. I wonder if its related to boost library version. Mine is 1.79

Comment: I can't repro even with 1.79, see [compiler explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/eqh6rd7sE) also ARM. The most striking difference is that your threads take a whopping 30ms to start. I'd suggest comparing with the `thread_pool` or inserting a 50ms sleep before initiation the `async_wait` just to see whether that changes the scheduling.

Comment: PS. consider pasting any results for legibility, e.g. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kfFS7jJth9/ from your comment

Comment: I tried thread_pool and delay before _async_wait_, no change in behavior. Only one worker thread is picking up both the handlers and it serializes them and another worker thread seem to be hung. I have to kill the app each time. Interesting observation is If I start both the timer tasks at the same time with 0ms then I can see both the threads picking up the handlers and they all exit properly (even with blocking sleep call inside both the handlers).